# display the list of users of a creche according to the creche of the authenticated user in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a creche management application and I would like to display the list of users according to the creche to which the authenticated user belongs.
For this I have three tables: user, creche and creche_user

Until then I manage to display users according to a given creche with the following code:

```
$user = Auth::user();

    if ($user->roles()->where('title', 'admin','user')->exists()) {
        $users = User::whereHas( 'roles', function($q)
        { 
            $q->where('title','<>', 'superAdmin'); 

        } )

        ->whereHas('creches', function ($q) {
            $q->where('nom', 'e-creche');
        })


        ->get();
    } else {
        $users = User::all();
    } 

    return view('admin.users.index', compact('users'));
```

My problem is that I do not want to specify the name of the creche as above "e-crèche".
I want to directly recover the creche to which the authenticated user belongs.

Thank you to those who respond!

Answer (score 0):

You may use relations directly like this

```
Auth::user()->creche
```

But you have to establish relation between the User.php and Creche.php
Something like this

```
User.php

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function creche(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Creche');
    }
}


Creche.php

class Creche extends Model
{
    public function users(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\User');
    }
}
```

Then you may get the creche of the authenticated user. 
More on relations here : [Laravel Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships)

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! I was able to find a solution by doing the following: ' $user = Auth::user();

$user->load('creches');

if ($user->roles()->where('title', 'admin')->exists()) {
    $users = User::whereHas('roles', function($query) { 
        $query->where('title', '<>', 'superAdmin'); 
    })->whereHas('creches', function ($query) use ($user) {
        $query->where('nom', $user->creches->first()->nom);
    })->get();
} else {
    $users = User::all();
} 

return view('admin.users.index', compact('users'));  '